# How to use This Script to Disable horizontal (left/right) mouse input during specific key hold

Tags: mouse, windows-11, macros, autohotkey, input-device

I am an Occupational Therapist working with a patient who has quadriplegia but had great head movement. He has Windows 11 and He wants to be able to hardcore game on his gaming laptop and we have been using an amazing head-mouse to allow him to easily navigate web pages and play point and click games like Runescape. However, in order to play games like Halo or Call of Duty, he needs to be able to recenter his head without the mouse registering this movement.
So I think he needs a script that will temporarily disable horizontal mouse movement with holding a key. We can link this key to a gesture(such as simply raising his eyebrows to press and hold this key).

I am a gamer but I have no idea how to make scripts or how to even make them work on a computer.
I saw another post that asked for this same script but only wanted to block
The script I from the original post was:

```
]::
   CoordMode, Mouse
   MouseGetPos, x
   ClipCursor(x, 0, 0, A_ScreenHeight)
return

] Up::
    ClipCursor()  ; Off
return


; https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=62856#p445668

ClipCursor(x := "", y := "", w := "", h := "") {
   if p := x != "" {
      VarSetCapacity(RECT, 16, 0), p := &RECT
      for k, v in [x, y, x + w, y + h]
         NumPut(v, p + 4*(k - 1), "Int")
   }
   DllCall("ClipCursor", "Ptr", p)
}
```

But I dont know what do do with any of this. Can someone please tell me exactly what to do to set this up?
Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.